# Dropzone.js invoke accept() function programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I use [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com) and I implemented a custom constraint for files that rejects files with the same filename. Heres my code of the initialisation:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", {
  url: MpgCommon.app.route('upload_files_path'),
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  thumbnailWidth: "80",
  thumbnailHeight: "80",
  dictCancelUpload: "Cancel",
  parallelUploads: 12,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  accept: function(file, done) {
    var selected_filenames = $.map(myDropzone.files, function(selected_file) {
      return (selected_file.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, ''));
    });
    var filename = file.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '')
    if ($.inArray(filename, selected_filenames) != selected_filenames.length-1){
      var error_msg = "Error!";
      $('.edit_tooltip .gui_message.error').css({display: "block"}).html(error_msg);
      done(error_msg);
    }
    else {
      $('.edit_tooltip .gui_message.error').css({display: "none"}).html('');
      done();
    }
  }
});
```

Now it seems that the accept function is called when a file is added but not when a file is removed from the dropzone. So is it possible to invoke the accept function programmtically?

I tried this, but it dosn't work:

```
myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file) {
  var rejected_files = myDropzone.getRejectedFiles();
  console.log(rejected_files);
  rejected_files.forEach(function () {
    console.log(this);
    myDropzone.accept(this);
  });
});
```

The error I get in the console is:

```
TypeError: done is not a function
if ( args ) {
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I responded to this question on github: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/257

Answer (score 0):

This is a less than optimal solution, but I've found that if you mimic the drop functionality with your existing files programmatically, you can achieve a similar result of 'reprocessing existing files'.

This involves storing the files to a variable, removing the files from the Dropzone object and adding the file(s) back in. From your javascript file do:

```
// Single file example. For multiple use dropzone.addFiles(dropzone.files);
var singleFile = dropzone.files[0];
if (singleFile) {
    dropzone.removeAllFiles(false);
    dropzone.addFile(singleFile);
}
```